# find third largest number in array java(including duplicates)

Tags: java, arrays, largenumber

This question might answered already but my problem is if i pass duplicate or repeated values in given array then its giving wrong output. As per logic is should give correct value but not sure whats wrong in my code. below is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;  

class ThirdLargest{

   static int thirdLar(int arr[],int arr_size)
   {
            int i, largest, secondLargest, thirdLargest; 


        thirdLargest = largest = secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
        for (i = 0; i < arr_size ; i ++) 
        { 
            /* If current element is smaller than 
            largest*/
            if (arr[i] > largest) 
            { 
                thirdLargest = secondLargest; 
                secondLargest = largest; 
                largest = arr[i]; 
            } 

            /* If arr[i] is in between largest and 
            secondLargest then update secondLargest */
            else if (arr[i] > secondLargest) 
            { 
                thirdLargest = secondLargest; 
                secondLargest = arr[i]; 
            } 

            else if (arr[i] > thirdLargest) 
                thirdLargest = arr[i]; 
        }  
        return thirdLargest;
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]){

      //Scanner object for capturing the user input
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


      //Stored the entered value in variable

        /*System.out.print("Enter 5 number of elements:");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();*/
        int n = 5;
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers one by one:");
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

      //Call thirdLar method to find largest number among given numbers
      int thirdLarNum = thirdLar(arr,n);
      System.out.println("The Third Largest Number is: "+thirdLarNum);
   }
}
```

**OUTPUT: If i pass values like 10 20 40 20 20
the correct output should be 10 but its returning 20**

Comment: I guess it's giving the correct result as you're allowing duplicates

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to include duplicates or not? Title says 'duplicates included', but in your example it looks like you want to ignore duplicates

Comment: @Illyes Istvan I mean it should ignore duplicates and need to give correct result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make sure `largest`, `secondLargest` & `thirdLargest` are unique, you should add more checks:

```
        ...
        else if (arr[i] > secondLargest && arr[i] != largest) 
                                        --------------------
        { 
            thirdLargest = secondLargest; 
            secondLargest = arr[i]; 
        } 

        else if (arr[i] > thirdLargest && arr[i] != largest && arr[i] != secondLargest) 
                                       -----------------------------------------------
            thirdLargest = arr[i]; 
        ...
```

Comment: Perfect answer that take O(n) and no extra space

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Set` instead of array to eliminate duplicate values and convert it to array

```
Set<int> set = new HashSet<>();

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    set.add(scanner.nextInt());
}

int thirdLarNum = thirdLar(set.toArray(), n);
```

Or use `set` in `thirdLar` instead of array

```
static int thirdLar(Set<int> set)
{
    for (int number : set) {
        if (number  > largest) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I don't want to import collections due to memory issues in project hence I'm trying to find by using arrays only

Answer (score 2):

You could use Streams :

I use here an IntStream which does not support a Comparator in sorted, which could allow a Collections.reverseSort(), so I have to negate every int before comparing – and return the negated value;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    static int thirdLar(final int[] arr) {

        final int[] array = Arrays.stream(arr).map(i -> -i).sorted().distinct().limit(3).toArray();

        return -array[Math.min(2, array.length - 1)];
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {

        System.out.println(thirdLar(new int[] { 1, 5, 2, 5, 10, 2, 2, 5, 10, 12, 25, 1, 5 }));

    }
}
```

**Edit** : this code allows easily for finding the nth largest

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    static int nthLargest(final int[] arr, final int rank) {

        assert rank > 0;

        final int[] array = Arrays.stream(arr).map(i -> -i).sorted().distinct().limit(rank).toArray();

        return -array[Math.min(rank - 1, array.length - 1)];
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {

        System.out.println(nthLargest(new int[] { 1, 5, 2, 5, 10, 2, 2, 5, 10, 12, 25, 1, 5 }), 3);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this by using below code.

```
int[] a = {1,10,33,55};
List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(a); 
int total = list.size; 
Collections.sort(list);  
int element=list.get(total-3);
```

Comment: would fail with `1,10,33,55,55`

Comment: @Ritesh Singh i think its not recommended logic as here we are just taking index element after sorting. it would fail with duplicates in this case